# Barra de progresso antes da função executar

Tags: html, jquery, materialize

Tenho uma página para emissão de certificado, e ela demora um certo tempo para criar a requisição e as chaves, pois é feito tudo no browser. Quero implementar uma barra de progresso para o usuário não ter a impressão que o site travou. Estou utilizando materialize da google e já tenho este código, o problema é que quando eu clico no botão, ao invés de aparecer a barra instaneamente, há um delay, que parece ser que está executando a função do OnClick() e então a barra aparece e já é redirecionado, a ideia é que a primeira coisa que aconteça é a barra aparecer.

Já tentei colocar dentro da função, criar outra função que chama essas duas, nada funciona, até em outros navegadores testei. Tentei usar jquerry, dom.

```
<button name="submitform" id="submitform" type="button" value="submit" onclick="generateKey()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn azul-icpedu-2" autocomplete="off">Submeter</button>

<div class="progress" style="display: none;">
    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#submitform").click(function(){
          $(".progress").css('display', 'block');
     });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    async function generateKey(){
        var keySize = $("#keygen").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var p12pw = $("#p12pw").val();

        if (p12pw === "") {
            location.reload();
        }


        sessionStorage.setItem("p12pw", JSON.stringify(p12pw));

        const publicKeyPem = await generateKeys(keySize, "privateKeyPem");

        $("#publickey").val(publicKeyPem);

        $("form").submit();
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Você tentou jogar o código que altera o CSS dentro da `generateKey()`?

Comment: Sim, acontece o mesmo efeito, há o delay

Comment: Me desculpe a pergunta que pode parecer idiota, mas você colocou o código que altera o CSS acima do await? Fiz um teste similar aqui e funcionou tranquilamente... O código: https://i.imgur.com/XWdAxfw.png

Comment: Sim, foi a primeira linha da função, mesmo assim não funciona

Comment: O seu código esta dentro de um form?

Comment: @WictorChaves a parte do botão e do div progress sim.